# Stuck in Sharepoint. How do I grow as a web developer when I'm stuck in Sharepoint?

Tags: javascript, web-application, web

I apologize if this is out of scope but I've seen other career type questions.

I can't just switch jobs because the only reason I'm a quasi developer in the first place is because my company let me use Sharepoint and I showed them I could do some complex stuff with Sharepoint. I have no formal background. I was hoping to just build from experience and my own self directed training.

But what appeals to me is the stuff thats happening client side these days with Javascript libraries that facilitate creating pure in page apps with AJAX calls. Or really just more customization in general. I've had a little success using spservices.js but its slow going and I feel like I'm often working against the Sharepoint environment I'm using it in. Implementation feels sloppy.

I'm hoping we can get a test installation of Sharepoint for my personal use soon so I can actually practice on the back end that I've been promised but not given to date (they're very skittish about that, a lot of us in different groups and programs are waiting.)

Do you have recommendations for such technologies that I could sell my stodgy conservative managers on letting me use? Any sources that might offer compelling arguments for letting our developers use them? Stuff executives would grok? I want to grow beyond glorified Sharepoint power user.

They'd be looking for stuff that integrates well with Sharepoint and doesn't create headaches when we upgrade Sharepoint versions (we're in 2010 now, supposedly transitioning to 2013 in the not too distant future.)

Alternately, if I'm just going to have to bite the bullet and work on this stuff strictly at home, then thats what I got to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask them for a reasonably powerful Virtual Machine and install SP2013 yourself.  SharePoint Foundation is free, as is SQL Server Express.  With those installed, you would be free to explore the vast array of client-side goodies packed into SP2013 without impacting anyone else.

If they need more of a business justification, point out that it also would serve and a place for proof-of-concept work as well as to support general SP2013 investigation.  You could even go one better and point out that such a server would also serve as a place to test upgrade existing Sharepoint content databases in preparation for the eventual full 2013 upgrade.

Comment: Ok. I ran that by my open-minded direct supervisor. Its iffy. My employer is a state agency, Sharepoint is controlled by a different program within the agency that we have to work with. I might be able to sell them on this on the basis that its one less thing to upgrade when we finally do, but if not, I guess what I should be asking is are there any good resources for do's and don'ts of developing 2010 stuff that will convert seamlessly or with only little effort to 2013?

Comment: The problem is, while it may be forever and a day before they move to Sharepoint 2013, they still don't want us straying far beyond out of the box implementation because that will create more work when they do upgrade (as we already experienced going from 2007 to 2010, which we're not done with yet.)

Comment: Do you have an MSDN account? If so, you can activate the Office 365 Developer subscription and get SharePoint Online running. There you can try to improve your JavaScript skills, because its the only way to customize it. Or, you can start using Windows Azure. With your MSDN account, you get free hours (amount depending on your subscription level) which you can use for Virtual Machines that run in the cloud. Let me know if you need help with that, i would love to help! Been in the same shoes as you were not too long ago...

Comment: I don't have that but it might be something my boss would entertain. Last I checked, it was too pricey for me to get on my own. I appreciate the suggestion and I might take you up on that if I get stuck.